# Access ARM processor registers from kernel space

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, embedded, kernel-module

I'm developing Linux kernel module for my Cubieboard2, kernel version 3.4.79. And i need to access peripherals configuration registers. I know how to do it from user space, but don't know about kernel space.

Also could you tell me what is better to drive GPIO with special functions like gpio_get_value() or gpio_set_value(), or do it through the configuration registers? What will be faster? And what if i need to drive array of GPIO as a port?

Comment: if you can do from user space, that is probably through an ioctl? check the kernel source for that

Comment: usually i do that by mapping physical memory to user space using mmap(), but how to do that for kernel space?

Comment: ioremap ? http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-9-sect-4 this question probably asked before on SO.

Comment: GPIO pins are usually not atomic for every operation.  For example, a read-modify-write to set a bit with `*p = *p | bit`; maybe interrupted/pre-empted and the first `*p` may refer to a bad value.  The `gpio_set_value()` should be written with these rare race problems in mind.  You should look at a GPIO driver and use these.  Even if you platform is ok, you may need to port to some new hardware with different GPIO configurations.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.